# Present UIPopoverController from a moving rect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipopovercontroller

Just got this weird problem, where I have a scroll view and buttons in the scroll view. I want to display a `UIPopover` from the button when touched, with `UITextFields` inside the `UIPopover`. The problem comes when the Keyboard appears. In certain cases, when the `UIButton` is so high in the view that the popover can only be displayed under it with the UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp, and when keyboard pops in, this popover cannot move any more up and therefore magically disappears to the top left corner (probably some Apple thing).

My solution is to check the frame of the `UIPopover` and to check that there is enough space for the keyboard, and if not, scroll the `UIScrollView` up with the buttons as well in order to be able to push the `UIPopover` up and so make sure that both the Keyboard and the popover fit.

So the question is: Is it possible to move the popover as the button moves?

Thanks